# Cannot create new zpool

Tags: zfs

I'm working on creating a ZFS zpool and I'm getting the following error:

> # zpool create main_zfs raidz2 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdk /dev/sdl /dev/sdm /dev/sdn /dev/sdo /dev/sdp /dev/sdq -f
>
> the kernel failed to rescan the partition table: 16
>
> cannot label 'sdc': try using parted(8) and then provide a specific slice: -1

I found another post on this subject [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146946/why-does-creating-a-zpool-result-in-this-error), but I can confirm that these disks have never been part of an MD array before.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. According to mount, none of these disks are currently mounted (they don't even have a file system anyway).
2. I've used zpool labelclear /dev/sd[c-q] to erase any ZFS metadata from them.
3. I've used dd to just zero the disks out.

Comment: Maybe name it mainzfs, without _.

Comment: What does dmesg say after this command?

Comment: Just tried naming it mainzfs.

Comment: Here's the dmesg:
[2667947.877379] Creating zpool
[2667958.300223]  sdc: sdc1 sdc9
[2667958.350206]  sdc: sdc1 sdc9

Comment: Did you reboot after dd?

Comment: No, no reboot after the dd. I actually did get the zpool to create following [this](http://thawedoutnow.blogspot.com/2014/11/when-zpool-create-command-fails.html) guide. I'm still working on figuring out exactly why something like that was necessary here.

Comment: Why would you create just one vdev ? this will be insanely slow ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `-f` right after the `create`.